# What is the css property to make items appear in a new row when the width is too small?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a container div that lists out an arbitrary number of elements.

When the number of elements do not fit in a row, then it should appear in a new row.

How can that be done?

Comment: See `CSS flex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) if not using flex or grid

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>wdiwbybwidbweibdiewbiwebiwebduewbduyewbuwebduwebweubuwebduewbdubweudbweubduwebuewbdewbewbiewbiwebdwehid</div>
```